# How to trigger a Lambda on S3 file upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I can't seem to get my lambda to trigger as I would expect. In AWS EventBridge, I created a rule with the following custom event pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": [
      "CopyObject",
      "CompleteMultipartUpload",
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["my-bucket"],
      "key": [{"prefix": "folder1/folder2/"}]
    }
  }
}
```

but when I upload a file to the "directory" the rule does not trigger the lambda.

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: you have enabled cloudtrail events for selected s3 bucket as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-cloudtrail-logging-for-s3.html#enable-cloudtrail-events)?

Comment: Three things: 1. Why not use S3 triggers directly? 2. The `eventNames` might miss the `s3:` prefix (e.g. `s3:PutObject`) and 3. did you give EventBridge permission to invoke your Lamdba?

Comment: @Jens - I think #3 might be the issue. Can you point me in the direction of docs that explain how to do that please?

Comment: I have tested your use case with cloud watch events, it works for me. Please find the below solution

Comment: 1. s3 event notification is coupled with the resource, there are reasons to prefer eventbridge. My question: I can't get mine to work either, are regions relevent? I have us-east-1 bucket and us-west-2 target. Are event bus setting needed? I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for the help and suggestions - all good resources should someone come across this post in the future. Turns out in my case @Balu Vyamajala was correct in the comments - I had incorrectly configured CloudTrail.

Comment: Please provide the solution, I'm still in the dark here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use event notification in S3. It has direct integration with Lambda, SNS, SQS

- Goto properties tab in S3
- Navigate to Event notification. click on create event notification.
  [image]
- Then add the event name.
- If you want to restrict the event to a specific folder or file type, you can fill in prefix or suffix fields or if you want it for entire bucket leave those blank.
  [image]
- Then select a list of events. like put, post.[image]
- Then choose the destination and click on save. You will be notified.
  [image]

Comment: My requirement is to use EventBridge Rules.

Comment: Hi Maxmoore14 
please find the below answer for the cloud watch event rule to put object

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021-11-29, Amazon Event Bridge now supports Amazon S3 Event Notifications **without having to enable CloudTrial**.

In the properties of the S3 bucket you want to monitor, you have to enable Amazon EventBridge.

[image]

This will allow you to send messages to EventBridge using Rules.
[image]

In your eventbridge rule, you can configure lambda as a "Target". I made a step-by-step tutorial on how to configure eventbridge in AWS if you want to follow along: https://youtu.be/k-jEuNb_KBM

Answer (score 1):

You can use both S3 events or cloud watch event rule to invoke the lambda function for any event on S3.

- Below Image shows how to configure cloud watch event rule for s3 putObject operation.
- Make sure you enabled cloud trail for data events in the respective region.
- Make sure you create a rule for the specific bucket.
- if you mention is for all the buckets. You will get unnecessary invocations, as cloud watch event rules works on cloud trail, where it will store all the logs to s3.
  [image]

Comment: Hope this is the answer you are expecting @maxmoore14

Comment: Seems like OP is trying to filter on a bucket prefix for events, is this also configurable in EventBridge? I couldn't find this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment to your question before, you might not have the proper permissions to allow `EventBridge` to `Invoke` your Lambda.

You can add the following `Resource-based policy` to your *Lambda*:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowExecutionFromEventBridge",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "<lambda-arn>",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "<eventbridge-rule-arn>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You need to replace `<lambda-arn>` and `<eventbridge-rule-arn>` with the respective values.

You can read more about `resource-based policy` here: [Using resource-based policies for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html).

If you use tools like Terraform, you can use the following snippet:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.example.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.example.arn
}
```

You need to replace `function_name` and `source_arn` here as well, with your specific references.